# Getting a CGPoint on a UIBezierpath

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cgpoint

In my app I have a MKOverlayPathView where I draw a QuadCurve between two points which works just fine.
Here is the code I use:

```
MKMapPoint mkDepPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate([(RoutePath *)self.overlay startCoordinate]);
MKMapPoint mkArrPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate([(RoutePath *)self.overlay endCoordinate]);
CGPoint dePoint = [self pointForMapPoint:mkDepPoint];
CGPoint arrPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:mkArrPoint];

CGPoint s = depPoint;
CGPoint e = arrPoint;

... some awesome code ...

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:s];
[path addQuadCurveToPoint:e controlPoint:cp1];
[path closePath];
```

Now I want to get a CGPoint for a specific percentage on that curve. I have been trying out a lot but I'm just not getting anwyhere useful. I have been trying this out but it's not really working:

```
CGPoint point = 
    CGPointMake(
    [self quadBezierForPercent:percent StartPoint:s.x ControlPoint:cp1.x EndPoint:e.x],
    [self quadBezierForPercent:percent StartPoint:s.y ControlPoint:cp1.y EndPoint:e.y]
);
```

Using this:

```
-(float)quadBezierForPercent:(float)t StartPoint:(float)start ControlPoint:(float)c1 EndPoint:(float)end {

    CGFloat t_ = (1.0 - t);
    CGFloat tt_ = t_ * t_;
    CGFloat tt = t * t;

    return start * tt_
    + 2.0 *  c1 * t_ * t
    + end * tt;
}
```

Some points in the right direction would be really helpful.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What you have looks reasonable. What are you seeing that you don't expect? Also, what is your expectation of what "percent" means? In general, a given value of `t` does not equal (`t * 100`)% along the length of the curve. Even divisions of `t` will fall along unequal amounts of the curve leaving gaps in some places and bunching up in others.

Comment: Percent here in my ist devided by 100. so for 30% I would use 0.3. The problem I am having is probably converting these point to coordinates on a map where I want to show them as annotation. They are all over the place but not where they are supposed to be.

Comment: `CLLocationCoordinate2D newPoint = [self.mapView convertPoint:mkOverlayView.point toCoordinateFromView:mkOverlayView];`